# How to find out error percentage in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have sample work history data data where history of pieces of work moving through the system are recorded. To do so, I selected rows based on error status which is end with '1'. Now, I tried to find error percentage from it but the output doesn't make sense to me.

Essentially, what I want to do is,  I want to answer the question like what percentage of pieces in this data set end up in an error status (error status is status end with digit 1) at least twice. Can anyone suggest possible approach to find error percentage in pandas? Thanks

**my current attempt**

```
import pandas

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/35def5060276a88ec5be30fe58f951c2/raw/e12b2b3b4da9988ae6c192e71546db58679d1f6a/work_flow_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)


err_status = [col for col in df['status'] if col[-1] in '1']
dff  = df.loc[df['status'].isin(err_status)]

P = q4_df.groupby('piece_id')['status'].size().reset_index()
P['Percentage'] = 100 * P['status']  / P['status'].sum()
```

above attempt didn't give me right answer because I want to know the percentage of pieces which is in error status at least twice more. How should I correct my attempt above? any idea?

Comment: @Serge de Gosson de Varennes I have quick question though, if we want to label the status that end with digit 3 as error, how to go around with that? any idea?

Comment: In the data that you shared, none of the status end with 3. But, if there were, you'd have to filter to only keep those that end by three. Something like ```dff = df[df['error']==3]```.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I think I figured this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. if I get your explanation right all `status` ending with 1 are errors. So, here is a way to do this. Maybe not the most beautiful, but it does the trick.

Step 1 is to create a column containing the last digit of the `status` number:

```
df['error'] = df['status'].astype(str).str[-1:]
```

which returns

```
 Unnamed: 0         id  piece_id  status      user_id  start_time  \
0             0  333831567  25395616   10800        911.0  1490989764   
1             1  333883698  25390812   10451   88738562.0  1491004450   
2             2  331993562  25265523   10450   88738561.0  1490021514   
3             3  327905898  24977108    8950        393.0  1487347396   
4             4  333065305  25353017   10451   88738560.0  1490647115   
..          ...        ...       ...     ...          ...         ...   
197         197  328106609  25008172    8601        169.0  1487625223   
198         198  326715370  24855982      21        393.0  1486156797   
199         199  330982999  25210529    9000        911.0  1489381774   
200         200  327005451  24877265    9000        911.0  1486513127   
201         201  334605362  25448390    1220  173935616.0  1491494567   

         end_time error  
0    1.491001e+09     0  
1    1.491005e+09     1  
2    1.490022e+09     0  
3             NaN     0  
4    1.490647e+09     1  
..            ...   ...  
197  1.487625e+09     1  
198  1.486157e+09     1  
199           NaN     0  
200           NaN     0  
201  1.491495e+09     0  

[202 rows x 8 columns]
```

Next, groupby the `piece_id` and count the error.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['piece_id'])['error'].count()).reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'error':'count errors'})
print(df2)

 piece_id  count errors
0    23681286             1
1    24037563             1
2    24039587             1
3    24044889             1
4    24065879             1
..        ...           ...
141  25395616             1
142  25419247             2
143  25445965             1
144  25447364             1
145  25448390             2

[146 rows x 2 columns]
```

Finally, extract all error counts larger than 1 (strictly) to get all piece_ids and take the percentage:

```
dff  = df2.loc[df2['count errors']>=2]
percentage = len(dff)/len(df)*100
```

which is `13.861386138613863`

Comment: I have quick question to ask here. If we want to label the status end with digit 3, how to go with that?